# How to store numbers in chunks from an array and create another array or list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I have two arrays x and y:

```
x = [2 3 1 1 2 5 7 3 6]
y = [0 0 4 2 4 5 8 4 5 6 7 0 5 3 2 8 1 3 1 0 4 2 4 5 4 4 5 6 7 0]
```

I want to create a list "z" and want to store group/chunks of numbers from y into z and the size of groups is defined by the values of x.

so z store numbers as

```
z = [[0,0],[4,2,4],[5],[8],[4,5],[6,7,0,5,3],[2,8,1,3,1,0,4],[2,4,5],[4,4,5,6,7,0]]
```

I tried this loop:

```
h=[]
for j in x:
    h=[[a] for i in range(j) for a in y[i:i+1]]
```

But it is only storing for last value of x.
Also I am not sure whether the title of this question is appropriate for this problem. Anyone can edit if it is confusing. Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to append to `h`, not reassign it each time through the loop.

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: h=[h.append(x) for i in range(j) for x in X[i:i+1]]   @Barmar like this?

Comment: No. `for j in x: h.append(...)`

Comment: array as in numpy.ndarray or the module array? or are you talking lists and just call them array? you are missing delimiting , between your numbers in that case. if you use numpy, tag the question as such.

Comment: The Dupe [how-to-split-or-break-a-python-list-into-unequal-chunks-with-specified-chunk-si](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640407/how-to-split-or-break-a-python-list-into-unequal-chunks-with-specified-chunk-si) tells you how to solve it, the other one is one of many examples that dupe the error you did - recreating the list _inside_ the loop on every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reassigning `h` each time through the loop, so it ends up with just the last iteration's assignment.

You should append to it, not assign it.

```
start = 0
for j in x:
    h.append(y[start:start+j])
    start += j
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it would be by using (and consuming as you do) an `iterator` like so:

```
x = [2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 6]
y = [0, 0, 4, 2, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0]

yi = iter(y)

res = [[next(yi) for _ in range(i)] for i in x]
print(res)  # -> [[0, 0], [4, 2, 4], [5], [8], [4, 5], [6, 7, 0, 5, 3], [2, 8, 1, 3, 1, 0, 4], [2, 4, 5], [4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0]]
```

Aside of the problem you are facing, and as a general rule to live by, try to give more meaningful names to your variables.